# How to get real path file name and rename it?

Tags: php, file-upload, file-rename

I'm trying to get path file name and post it to sql table, actually my code is really complicated and I couldn't find a solution for this. Here is main part of my code that it's straight to the my question point.

```
        $test->setPathFilename('../tests/' . $_FILES['path_filename']['name']);
```

In above code, it will get real path file name, and it will upload it to **tests folder** and it will get file name by **['name']** and it will post it to sql table name **path_filename**

in my public PHP file, the **file name** is handling by this following code:

```
        $destinationName = $file['name'];
```

So, now everything is working well. the problem is about when file is exist, then it will be replaced it to existing file. that's why I tried to rename file while uploading automatically, by using this code:

```
$ext = pathinfo($file["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$destinationName = sha1_file($file["tmp_name"]).time().".".$ext;
```

So, now if file name is ABC.png , it will be renamed to such as name like this: 56944555554554.png for example!

but still path file name is as real file name not renamed one in first code  I mean this:

```
        $test->setPathFilename('../tests/' . $_FILES['path_filename']['name']);
```

As I know, **['name']** in above line is real path file name, I mean **ABC.png**

That's why when upload is succeed then it won't show it cause in sql table, file name has been saved by real name, ABC.png but in fact, the file name has been renamed into tests folder.

How can I solve this puzzle? Please help me on this matter.

I really appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

Thank you so much